# Why do I get "The server encountered a stack overflow during compile time" error is SQL Server 2000 Sp4

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to have around 6290 'AND' conditions in this query. I get the same for around 11945 'OR' conditions.

Exception details:
 The server encountered a stack overflow during compile time.   at System.Data.
lClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException excepti
, Boolean breakConnection)

Comment: Sounds like you found the boundary conditions.  I'd really reconsider a design that caused you to have 6290 'AND' conditions in a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting bug!  The obvious question to ask you is, *why?*  The stack overflow is because recursion is the typical way to parse an SQL statement like that, which builds up a syntax tree.  Depending on what is pushed onto the stack with each recursive call, it's not surprising.  Did it hurt the server?  ;)

Comment: Thanks; this answer explained the possible situation why we do not see it more often on our DB servers.

Answer (score 2):

Try and optimise your AND/OR conditions.

```
SELECT * FROM foo
WHERE ([fooKey] = 1 AND Year = 1995)
OR ([fooKey] = 1 AND Year = 1996)
OR ([fooKey] = 1 AND Year = 1997)
OR ([fooKey] = 1 AND Year = 1998)
OR ([fooKey] = 1 AND Year = 1999)
OR ([fooKey] = 1 AND Year = 2000)
OR ([fooKey] = 1 AND Year = 2001)
OR ([fooKey] = 1 AND Year = 2002)
... ad infinitum
```

becomes

```
SELECT * FROM fooWHERE ([fooKey] = 1 AND Year between 1995 and 2002)
union
SELECT * FROM fooWHERE ([fooKey] = 10017 AND Year = 1995)
union
SELECT * FROM fooWHERE ([fooKey] = 10018 AND Year = 1997)
... slightly less
```

Or go to 64 bit and try and add enough memory for this not to happen...

Comment: Thanks for answering this question. I do not have control on the ids (unique ids). probably I can think of running queries in batches.